# Installing crossvc is giving broken packages error

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, qt3

I am having Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. While trying to install `crossvc`, I am getting broken package error.

I tried to find solutions and tried all the suggested steps in different posts. But no success.

- LOGS for `sudo apt-get install crossvc`

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
  or been moved out of Incoming.
  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   crossvc : Depends: libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8-b) but it is not installable
  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
  ```
- LOGS for `sudo aptitude install crossvc`

  ```
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    crossvc{b} libfam0{a} 
  0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 1300 kB of archives. After unpacking 4048 kB will be used.
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   crossvc : Depends: libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8-b) which is a virtual package.
  The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Keep the following packages at their current version:
  1)     crossvc [Not Installed]                            



  Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

  *** No more solutions available ***

  The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Keep the following packages at their current version:
  1)     crossvc [Not Installed]                            



  Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
  ```
- LOGS when installing using Ubuntu Software Center

  ```
  Package dependencies cannot be resolved

  This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

  Details:
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  crossvc: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
           Depends: libqt3-mt (>= 3:3.3.8-b) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
  ```
- Other option tried

  Even I tried with doing the below for resolving broken package [referred from different posts] but no success.

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
  dpkg --get-selections | grep hold [ no package listed ]
  ```

Comment: To CLOSE queue reviewers, [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) does not cover deprecated packages. `libqt3-mt` wasn't released after Precise.

Comment: Hi Sneetsher, I tried with the below package. $ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/c/crossvc/crossvc_1.5.2-2_i386.deb.

Comment: Then it's the same version as mine. Could you try my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libqt3-mt` is old Qt3 deprecated lib in favor of Qt4. It is available only in Lucid and Precise repositories:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libqt3-mt

1. Download Precise package from (choose a mirror):

   http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libqt3-mt

   Example, 64bit:

   ```
   wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt-x11-free/libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb
   ```

   32Bit:

   ```
   wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt-x11-free/libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
   ```
2. Install it, 64bit::

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb
   ```

   32bit:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libqt3-mt_3.3.8-b-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
   ```

Try with crossvc again. It should work as I have tested it in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Still missing some dependencies, Search using http://packages.ubuntu.com/:

- If that package is built for your release, you follow instruction in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)
- Else, download closest release build & install it same as above.

Comment: I tried above. it is asking asking for some more dependencies. $ dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt3-mt:
 libqt3-mt depends on libmng1 (>= 1.0.10); however:
  Package libmng1 is not installed.
  
dpkg: error processing package libqt3-mt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt3-mt

Comment: @Satish, updated my answer, you could use same way to fix related dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

//     installing it on 32 bit

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/c/crossvc/crossvc_1.5.2-2_i386.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i crossvc_1.5.2-2_i386.deb
```

// 64 bit

```
$ wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/c/crossvc/crossvc_1.5.2-2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i crossvc_1.5.2-2_amd64.deb
```

// if that didnt workout with you you should wait for the next version of it

its not apt problem its repository prob

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried with above and the error still persists.